# Qt Linguist not loading context from .po files

Tags: qt, translation, qt-linguist

I have been working with translations directly with Qt Linguist but, recently, other contributors without access to Qt started using other tools. Our exchange format is PO. Qt Linguist saves the PO file with contexts but, when importing PO files from the other contributors, these contexts are stripped.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was simple to solve. In the headers of the new PO file the following line must be present:

```
"X-Qt-Contexts: true\n"
```

This solves the issue.